# Modules with repeated names on angular dependency

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I've been using angular 4 and suddenly It prompt me with an error and a warning when I was doing a service and inject the  `Http` in the service, I believe the problem actually comes from the warning:

```
./~/@angular/Http/@angular/http.es5.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem 
with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:

* /Users/centroagdigital/Documents/...ui/node_modules/@angular/Http/@angular/http.es5.js
Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
.../components/company-select/company-select.service.ts
```

The actual error is:

```
Error: No provider for Http!
at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
```

Here are the classes where I use this module:

`company-select.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CompanySelect } from './company-select.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'; 

// service
import { CompanySelectService } from './company-select.service'

@NgModule({
  providers: [ 
     CompanySelectService
  ],
  declarations: [
    CompanySelect
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CompanySelect
  ]
})
export class CompanySelectModule { }
```

`company-select.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/Http';

// models
import { Company } from './models/company.interface'

@Injectable()
export class CompanySelectService
{
    constructor(private http : Http){}
    getCompanies() // : Company[] not implemented yet
    {
       return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: How about changing `import { Http } from '@angular/Http';` to `import { Http } from '@angular/http';` in your service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CompanySelectModule, you use `import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';`
with lowercase 'h' then in your CompanySelectService, you use `import { HttpModule } from '@angular/Http';` with a capital 'H' !

As @Harry Ninh suggested, try to change the import in your CompanySelectService to use lowercase 'h'